# revision disappeared in ear artifact

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I recently upgraded from Hudson 1.385 to Jenins 1.433 and something strange happened after the upgrade.

My modules used to look like this:  vrs-ws-ear-r17229-4.0.7-SNAPSHOT.ear (with the revision number in the artifact r172229)

Since the upgrade jenkins stopped putting the revision number into the artifacts, like this: vrs-ws-ear-4.0.7-SNAPSHOT.ear

When i run: mvn clean install on the command line on my server then everything comes out as expected, however as soon as I run the step with Jenkins then the revision is gone.   I also see the following exception but am not sure what to do about it:

```
Oct 6, 2011 4:32:44 PM hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter doUnmarshal
WARNING: Skipping a non-existent field revPropSupport
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.NonExistentFieldException: No such field hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.revPropSupport
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary.field(FieldDictionary.java:106)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.getFieldType(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:152)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.determineType(RobustReflectionConverter.java:356)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:229)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:180)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:82)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:63)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:76)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:60)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:137)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:33)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:926)
        at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:91)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:912)
        at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:156)
        at hudson.model.Descriptor.load(Descriptor.java:753)
        at hudson.scm.SCMDescriptor.load(SCMDescriptor.java:80)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.<init>(SubversionSCM.java:1708)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl$$FastClassByGuice$$7f042112.newInstance(<generated>)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:60)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
        at hudson.ExtensionFinder$AbstractGuiceFinder$1$1.get(ExtensionFinder.java:252)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
        at hudson.ExtensionFinder$AbstractGuiceFinder.find(ExtensionFinder.java:221)
        at hudson.ExtensionFinder._find(ExtensionFinder.java:110)
        at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:285)
        at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:258)
        at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:229)
        at hudson.ExtensionList.iterator(ExtensionList.java:136)
        at hudson.diagnosis.NullIdDescriptorMonitor.verify(NullIdDescriptorMonitor.java:65)
        at hudson.diagnosis.NullIdDescriptorMonitor.verifyId(NullIdDescriptorMonitor.java:86)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at hudson.init.InitializerFinder.invoke(InitializerFinder.java:110)
        at hudson.init.InitializerFinder$TaskImpl.run(InitializerFinder.java:174)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:259)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:798)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:187)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:94)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:650)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:675)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Oct 6, 2011 4:33:00 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol pause
```

Comment: The exception should be harmless. You can fix that by going to Manage Jenkins, then pressing the "Manage" button at the top of the page, where it mentions obsolete data.

Comment: @Christopher, you are right.  I just installed a fresh, new Jenkins and the exception does not come up but the revision is actually still not being output by Jenkins, but it is output by command-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that with the new Jenkins they removed this functionality.  But in order to get it back you can click 'archive the artifacts' inside 'configure.'  This will allow you input "project/**/*.ear,project/***/.jar" if you wish to display the artifacts 'project/subfolder/build-rev1234-a.ear'